# Java Async HTTP Request

Tags: java, asynchronous, xmlhttprequest, synchronization, httprequest

I want to send multiple request to a source but before send a request, need to wait until previous request return a value.

I did it with JavaScript like below. How can I do it with Java?

```
var httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
var requestDest = '';

var responseStr = [];

(function launchRequest(currentPosition) {
    var requestParam = ``;

    httpRequest.open('POST', requestDest, false); <-- third parameter doing this.
    httpRequest.setRequestHeader('', '');
    httpRequest.send(requestParam);

    if (httpRequest.readyState == 4) 
        if (httpRequest.statusText == 'OK')
            responseStr.push(JSON.parse(httpRequest.responseText));

    if (currentPosition < 50) launchRequest(currentPosition + 1);
})(0);
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Javascript and Java are fundamentally different languages.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.